# Can't log into my Kali Linux VM no matter what I do

Tags: linux, virtualbox, login

I am fairly experienced in downloading and installing a variety of Kali Linux distributions and I have never once had this issue.

I just recently downloaded the 2020.4 ISO file image for Kali (kali-linux-2020.4-installer-amd64.iso) for 64 bit.

I followed all the steps for installation, 2 times I even watched a tutorial yet I always have the same issue: I cannot login. It is insane and I am extremely frustrated. I have tried every single combination of root/toor kali/kali admin username/root every thing I could find online it's all useless. Naturally on my maybe 5th attempt of reinstalling it I tried a simple username like username123 and password 123, even took a photo and it didn't work. I've completely scrubbed virtualbox off my machine then reinstalled it twice already nothing I can think of works. If you are going to help me please heed what I have written as I have already gone to other forums where they give me responses like "You must have forgotten your password" or "try reinstalling". Any help at all is appreciated and please comment anything you think that is reasonable as in my personal opinion I think I am missing something simple. Feel free to ask any questions that are tech related about my system I am somewhat educated in technology and can probably answer. Thanks in advance for answers.

Edit: I have already tried opening terminal on the login page, same circumstances.

Comment: I cannot log in this way. I tried the same combos of passwords with it, didn't work

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. I have Kali 2020.4 VMs on two machines. One fresh install and I had to do what I suggested above and one upgrade from 2019 - no issues. So i am not sure. I will look around a bit.